# can't edit product in magento 2. redirect to 504 connection error

Tags: magento2, database

In magneto 2, after editing product its shows please wait loader and redirect to 504 connection timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a timeout issue from the server. Please check your server load and usages reports.

Comment: we already check server execution time.but its show same error again

Comment: Check the network tab of the browser when you submit after edit product.

Comment: check it .It take 1.0 min to load page.